# ) в теле цикла командной строки

Tags: cmd, bat, экранирование

Помогите, плиз, решить вопрос. Вот написал такой батник:

```
cd /d %0\..
echo off
for /l %%k in (1,1,3) do (
echo (%%k) >> file%%k.txt   
)
```

При его выполнении получаются файлы 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, содержание коих (1, (2, (3 соответственно. Но заказывал-то я скобки с обоих сторон! Очевидно, проблема в том, что cmd.exe воспринимает закрывающую круглую скобку около параметра цикла скобкой, парной открывающей круглой скобке после

```
do
```

Но как эту проблему решить? Гугл что-то невнятное говорит про закрывающую круглую скобку в теле цикла, там, про экранирование, а что конкретно делать, умалчиваетъ, гад.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, а почему 2 крышки?

Answer (score 2):

В бат символы экранируются при помощи `^`. Все, что вам нужно, это поставить символ `^` перед `)`

```
for /l %%k in (1,1,3) do (
  echo (%%k^) >> file%%k.txt   
)
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в текстовой файл через батник ввести строку *for(int i=0; i <= n; ++i)*?

Comment: Сам *for * не вводит.

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался:

```
echo for(int i=0; i ^<= n; ++i^) { >>sphera.asy
```

Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Может все таки стоит отметить мой вопрос как верный? Учитывая что он полностью отвечает на исходный вопрос

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, это вы мне?

Comment: @Geek, да, вам. Вы получили исчерпывающий ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Да, да, извините, пожалуйста, я отметил.